# Use Discord's API to send message as user

Tags: discord

I want to send a message in a Discord channel but from a user account not a bot. Is this kind of thing possible using Discord's API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official documentation should contain enough information to get started: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message

Make sure to login with OAuth2 and not as a bot. Also, it is important to get the right scope (permissions) when requesting an OAuth token.

Comment: So what scopes should i set?

Comment: You need 'SEND_MESSAGES' permission, but in the list of scopes at https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes there is only 'messages.read' to read messages from a channel. There is also 'bot' and 'applications.commands', but I guess that is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Did you found a solution ? I'm in the same case

Comment: Have the same issue right now do you found any solution to send private message without a bot?

Comment: @VincentBitter In case anyone wondering as well. Click the 'Bot' scope, then add at least `VIEW_CHANNEL` and `SEND_MESSAGE` permission.

Comment: Discord API doesn't seem to allow sending messages as a user and not a bot. Bots can only send messages under their own account.